# PHP Canvas unable to show up

Tags: php, arrays

```php
$sql = "SELECT count(order_id) as counti, order_date FROM order_detail GROUP BY order_date ORDER BY order_date DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        $dataPoints = [];
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {          
                $new_data= array("label"=> $row['order_date'], "y"=> $row['counti']);  
                $dataPoints= array_merge($dataPoints, $new_data);                
            } 
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Unable to load GraphModel");</script>';
        }
```

Edit: Just tried change to while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) but the value unable to show up from the canvasjs
Default of the array i use without the database data look this below

```
$dataPoints = array(
    array("label"=> "Education", "y"=> 284935),
    array("label"=> "Entertainment", "y"=> 256548),
    array("label"=> "Lifestyle", "y"=> 245214),
    array("label"=> "Business", "y"=> 233464),
    array("label"=> "Music & Audio", "y"=> 200285),
    array("label"=> "Personalization", "y"=> 194422),
    array("label"=> "Tools", "y"=> 180337),
    array("label"=> "Books & Reference", "y"=> 172340),
    array("label"=> "Travel & Local", "y"=> 118187),
    array("label"=> "Puzzle", "y"=> 107530)
);
```

My error from https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js

```
canvasjs.min.js:208 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
    at p._processMultiseriesPlotUnit (canvasjs.min.js:208)
    at p._processData (canvasjs.min.js:206)
    at p.setLayout (canvasjs.min.js:188)
    at p.render (canvasjs.min.js:201)
    at window.onload (index.php:104)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `mysqli_fetch_array()` be inside the loop so you can iterate through the result set?

Comment: Your while loop is referencing the wrong function, you want something like `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` instead.

Comment: `while($row = mysqli_num_rows($result))` is a never-ending condition when there are results returned. You basically get `while (4)` (when there are four rows), and that is an infinite loop.

Comment: Thanks @jamesinc. I just tried your fetch_assoc, now it not loop forver anymore but now the canvasjquery doesn't recognize the $dataPoint value to show it up. The error i uploaded above :(

Comment: Problem solved. Please look into the answer if you have same problem like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the problem. Since i don't set the $new_data as array so the $dataPoints unable to find the arrays id to show up. Here how i fix it

```
<?php
        $sql = "SELECT count(order_id) as counti, order_date FROM order_detail GROUP BY order_date ORDER BY order_date DESC";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $dataPoints = array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {          
                $new_data = array("label"=> $row['order_date'], "y"=> $row['counti']);  
                $dataPoints = array_merge($dataPoints, array($new_data));   
                print_r($dataPoints);               
            };
        }
        else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Unable to load GraphModel");</script>';
        }

    ?>
```